# tweening a css color property, preferrably with tweenlite javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, css-transitions, gsap

I have a button which inverts the colors on my website. It utilizes a plugin called rgb color - http://www.phpied.com/rgb-color-parser-in-javascript/ to get the color value of all dom elements, and invert them. I'm doing that with the code below:

```
invertColors: function(){
      var colorProperties = ['color', 'background-color'];

      //iterate through every element
      $('*').each(function() {
        var color = null;

        for (var prop in colorProperties) {
            prop = colorProperties[prop];
            if (!$(this).css(prop)) continue; //if we can't find this property or it's null, continue
            color = new RGBColor($(this).css(prop)); //create RGBColor object
            if (color.ok) { //good to go, build RGB
              var element = $(this);
              $(this).css(prop, 'rgb(' + (255 - color.r) + ', ' + (255 - color.g) + ', ' + (255 - color.b) + ')'); //subtract each color component from 255
            }
            color = null; //some cleanup
        } //end each for prop in colorproperties
      }); //end each
    } //end invert colors
```

What I'd like to do is rather than just flip the color, tween it. I'm curious to try the greensock tweening engine, as it is supposedly up to 20 times faster than jquery's, but if I have to, I can use a different method. Their tween engine is documented here:

http://www.greensock.com/get-started-js/#css

So supposedly, I should be able to make a call something like this:

```
TweenLite.to(element, 1, {css:{prop:'rgb(' + (255 - color.r) + ', ' + (255 - color.g) + ', ' + (255 - color.b) + ')' }, ease:Power2.easeOut});
```

but this is not working (no errors are thrown), so I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. Anyone have any ideas for how to get this working, or what the fastest way to tween all of these color properties would be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't figured out how to do it with a tweening engine or even requestAnimationFrame, but I did it with css transitions:

```
this.invertColors = function(){
      var colorProperties = ['color', 'background-color'];

      //iterate through every element
      $('*').each(function() {

        var $thisElement = $(this);

        for (var prop in colorProperties) {
            prop = colorProperties[prop];
            if (!$(this).css(prop)) continue; //if we can't find this property or it's null, continue
            color = new RGBColor($(this).css(prop)); //create RGBColor object
            if (color.ok) { //good to go, build RGB
              var newColor = new RGBColor('rgb(' + Math.abs(255-color.r) + ', ' + Math.abs(255-color.g) + ', ' + Math.abs(255-color.b) +')');
              if (prop == "background-color"){
                $thisElement.css({'transition':'background 1s'});
                $thisElement.css({'background-color': 'rgb('+newColor.r+','+newColor.g+','+newColor.b+')'});
              } else {
                $thisElement.css({'transition':'color 1s'});
                $thisElement.css({'color': 'rgb('+newColor.r+','+newColor.g+','+newColor.b+')'});
              }

              //$thisElement.css(prop, 'rgb(' + Math.abs(255 - color.r) + ', ' + Math.abs(255 - color.g) + ', ' + Math.abs(255 - color.b) + ')'); //subtract each color component from 255
            }
            color = null; //some cleanup
        } //end each for prop in colorproperties*/
      }); //end each
    } //end invert colors
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved here: 
http://forums.greensock.com/topic/7101-tweening-a-css-color-propertys-r-g-b-values/#entry26465

You can definitely do this with GSAP. The problem had to do with not assigning the property correctly (you were literally asking TweenLite to tween "prop" instead of "color" or "backgroundColor") and TweenLite needs camelCase properties ("backgroundColor", not "background-color").

```
function invertColors() {
    var colorProperties = ['color', 'backgroundColor'];
 
    //iterate through every element
    $('*').each(function() {
        var color = null,
           obj, css, prop;
       for (prop in colorProperties) {
           prop = colorProperties[prop];
           obj = $(this);
           if (!obj.css(prop)) continue; //if we can't find this property or it's null, continue
           css = {};
           color = new RGBColor(obj.css(prop));
           if (color.ok) { 
               css[prop] = 'rgb(' + (255 - color.r) + ', ' + (255 - color.g) + ', ' + (255 - color.B) + ')';
               TweenLite.to(this, 2, {css:css});
            }
        } 
    }); 
}
```